# Please explain the result of this query

Tags: sql, windows, ms-access-2007

When I run this query:

```
SELECT InwardDate
FROM tblDoc
WHERE InwardDate > DATE() AND (InwardDate IS NOT NULL)
```

I get this result

```
5/1/2017
```

The row I have in the database has the value:

```
5/1/2017
```

So, `5/1/2017` is not `> 5/1/2017` and the result should be no records returned.

I then went and tried this, in case there is a time difference that I can't see:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("s", InwardDate, DATE()) AS DiffBetween, InwardDate
FROM tblDoc
WHERE InwardDate > DATE() AND (InwardDate IS NOT NULL)
```

I get:

[image]

Note that when I do:

```
SELECT DATE() FROM tblDoc
```

I get:

```
5/1/2017
```

I see that the first query is returning an apparently illogical result because the date stored in the db has the same exact value as that in the SQL but the first query says the db column value is larger than the date returned by the `DATE()` function.  What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where I am currently, it is 5/1/2017.

If so, a value of that date will, of course, be excluded:

```
WHERE INWARDDATE > Date()
```

> the datediff, should have reported a value if the 2 dates were not the
>   same.

Well, yes, but you have no records returned, thus no datediff.

The value you see is the *default value* of InwardDate on a new record (the *).

Comment: Thank you for you help, but, WHERE InwardDate > DATE() AND (InwardDate IS NOT NULL) produces a single result row of of 5/1/2017.

Comment: That should have a `*` on the left too. Try removing the default value of the column `InwardDate` to make things clearer.

Comment: @Andre, your point about "*" prefix and the fact that it does not represent a real row is very good. In fact, if I replace the entire WHERE expression by "WHERE FALSE" I still get the same result. Your additional spotting for the Default Value of the column is a great point too. Thank you very much.

Comment: I now see what you mean. Yes there is a default value and that is just what is showing there. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

date() returns the current date (4/30/17) when you posted this.  So it's returning Inward date if it's > than today's date and is not null.  5/1/17 is > 4/30/17 and is not null, therefore it returns it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, where I am currently, it is 5/1/2017. I made an edit to the question to mention this...Time zones could indeed be tricky. Also, the datediff, should have reported a value if the 2 dates were not the same.

Comment: Is the sql server located in your timezone?  Also try just outputing the result of date() to see what it is.

Comment: Good point, I am trying this on MS-Access with MS-Access back end and not with a SQL-Server backend. The db is on my machine.